# jQuery UI Datepicker - Inline - Close button disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm using jQuery Datepicker in my CMS.

I'm using this plugin to make selecting multiple dates: https://github.com/dubrox/Multiple-D...-for-jQuery-UI

The calendar flashes and reappears in the current month when I select dates previous months.
The flashes example with multidates select: http://jsfiddle.net/cza76nrx/1/

To "try" to fix this I used a piece of code to let INLINE when opened.
This is the code.

```
onSelect: function()          
      {
      $(this).data('datepicker').inline = true;                               
      }
```

Example with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/cza76nrx/2/
Issue:
It does not close when I click on other form elements or when pulse outside the document

I actived the close button to close it manually but when I press a date close button disappear.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cza76nrx/3/

Why can this happen?

Comment: Your fiddle does not work, since all the stuff under http://www.javiscript.es/PROTOS cannot be found.